# Where to save customized behavior for doctrine in a symfony1.4 project?

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, behavior

So that the behavior template can be autoloaded when necessary.

I'm confused by the complex settings.

Answer (score 1):

I put them in lib/doctrine, and if there's a listener as well, put that in lib/doctrine/listener.

Symfony's autoloader will find the classes and load them for you pretty much wherever you put them (as long as its vaguely logical). The only exception is if you create a new vendor folder, you will need to tell the autoloader to check there as well.

Comment: I would have said `lib/doctrine/template/` and `lib/doctrine/listener/` but well `lib/doctrine/` is the actual important part :-)

Comment: Do you mean `sfproject\lib\vendor\symfony-1.4.1\lib\plugins\sfDoctrinePlugin\lib\vendor\doctrine\Doctrine\Template` ?

Comment: sfproject\lib\doctrine - folder won't exist, you need to make it. it'll be alongside your model, form etc folders. putting it where you suggest is a bad idea as you'll end up overwriting it if you upgrade symfony.